# Ruby 1.9: Break statement from recursive functions now a syntax error?

Tags: ruby, textmate, ruby-1.9, ruby-1.9.2, textmatebundles

I'm updating a bundle (GetBundles) to be compatible with Ruby 1.9 (1.9.2 specifically).

This script uses 
`break if $close`
in a (I'm assuming) recursive function.  I'm assuming this is a recursive function since break doesn't make sense otherwise (this is not in a block except for the top-level function def).  This is giving me a syntax error, however I couldn't find anything in the Ruby changelog that says it's now illegal.  Is this now an error, or is it a bug in the script?

Secondly, would
`return if $close`
be an equivalent replacement?

Thanks!

Comment: *"I'm assuming this is a recursive function since break doesn't make sense otherwise (this is not in a block except for the top-level function def)."* - Actually, the reverse is true; a return makes sense, a break does not.

Comment: Can you provide a code sample that produces the same error, and provide the actual error message provided by Ruby?

Comment: The code is rather convoluted, but it's a moot point now anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 solutions: use the system Ruby 1.8.7 or use TM2.